# Open Website not found in Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, settings

After fresh installation of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in lap, I am unable to find New/Open Website in my Start Page and File Menu. See the below image for details.
[image: Visual Studio Start Page]
What should I do to get the New/Open Website back?

P.S: Although I am not sure, I attribute this to initial settings I choose on the first run of Visual Studio Ultimate. I have selected some thing like **General Development Settings**. Will changing to **Web Developer Settings** solve the problem? If so, how to change the settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nuclear option is to enter the `Tools` > `Import and Export Settings...` dialog, choose `Reset All Settings...`, and then pick one of the "Web Development" templates.

Be forewarned that this will reset *everything*, such as your fonts/colors, code indent/formatting preferences, etc.  However, you can selectively restore sections of your current settings if you make a backup of them before resetting.  So, you could reset to get your menus back, but then restore the fonts, colors, and indent/formatting sections of your old setup, as long as you make a backup during the reset process.

Comment: I tried that. and in the default collection of settings there are only general development settings and project management settings and this also wont solve my problem :(

Comment: It sounds like your installation is missing the web development features altogether.  Can you open/create web application projects?  If you have the install DVD handy, you could use the setup application to double check that the `Visual Web Developer` feature is installed.  If it already is, try running a repair/reinstall from setup.

Comment: yep. that nsolved it. thanks. I was really hoping for a settings change. But guess the settings was not even installed and so couldn't use that method.

Answer (score 1):

Try:  Right click on the toolbar [section] of the window, and select 'Customize'.  Go to the 'Commands' tab and click 'Reset All'.  See if that helps.

Comment: +1: no it doesn't work. but its good if settings are installed